# evict atomiclong in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I'd like to have multiple atomic longs in Hazelcast, lets say one with name "atomic_1" and another with name "atomic_2", I want to evict "atomic_1" every day from time of creation and I want to evict "atomic_2" every hour from the time of creation. I'm using `hazelcast-spring`

Answer (score 1):

You can start with maintaining a mapping of all instances of IAtomicLong that you create with their names in an IMap, with setting TTL on each map entry. That way when a map entry (the IAtomicLong instance name in your case) is evicted, you listen to that event (entryEvicted or entryExpired) and explicitly ***destroy*** the corresponding IAtomicLong from the cluster within that event listener.

Comment: thanks, but in that case I rather just use the map's value instead of a IAtomicLong